# Running nodejs, sqlite3 in dockerfile on raspberrypi 4

Tags: node.js, docker, sqlite, raspberry-pi4

```
FROM arm32v7/ubuntu:18.04 
RUN apt-get -y install curl gnupg
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x  | bash -
RUN apt-get -y install nodejs
#RUN apt-get install -y npm
RUN npm install sqlite3


WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . .
RUN npm install
CMD ["node",  "/usr/src/app/server/index.js"]
```

---

I am getting this error : -

npm ERR! Tracker "idealTree" already exists

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2023-04-27T15_11_38_675Z-debug-0.log

Answer (score 0):

Does your folder already have a node_modules folder? Try deleting that. Or make sure node_modules is specified in the .dockerignore file in your folder.

Also, I would remove the first npm install from your Docker file. It's installing sqlite3 into the image in whatever default folder is initially selected. If that's not the cause of the problem, it's definitely making your image bigger than it needs to be.